# Creating an arc/arch or semi-circle without the diameter line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm fairly new to Illustrator, and trying to figure out how to create an arc that doesn't have the bottom line that you get from using the `Minus Front` shape mode.

For example, if I start with a circle like this:

[image]

And then either add a rectangle or just draw a simple line through it like this:

[image]

Using the `Minus Front` shape mode will give me a half circle that has the diameter line from the rectangle

[image]

The `Divide` option also gives the same results here.

Is there a simple way for me to achieve what I need? See below for a (bad) example I just drew over in paint

[image]

Also not sure if there's a big difference, but I also want to achieve this with an oval, which is where my inexperience with the pen tool comes in and makes things difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the Minus Front operation, simply use the **Direct Selection tool** (the White arrow) to click the bottom path and then hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key..

[image]

But.. if you want the entire upper (or lower) half of a circle/ellipse, you don't really need Pathfinder at all. Because there are anchors on all 4 sides of the curve to create the smooth path. You merely need to delete 1 anchor and you are left with 50% of the shape.

Just use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select the bottom anchor and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>...

[image]

Comment: Amazed every day over how much I tend to overcomplicate things in Illustrator... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Using Scissors Tool**

1. Create the circle
2. Select *Scissors Tool* <kbd>C</kbd> or from the tools bar.
3. Select the circle. Hover upon the two anchor points and click on each of them

   *(Use Smart Guides if you want a little more guidance. But it's not necessary as once you select the circle, you can see 4 individual
   anchor points are highlighted)*
4. It will divide the circle into two separate paths. Select any one of them and delete it.

[image]

**Using Pathfinder**

1. Create the circle
2. Create a rectangle over it where you want to cut it
3. Select both shapes, go to Pathfinder Panel and click ***Outline***. It will split the shapes on intersections
4. Doing so will remove all stroke weights. Apply any stroke width again so you can see them.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Windows) to ungroup everything.
6. Select the unwanted shapes and delete them
   [image]

Comment: There's almost *never* a reason to use the Scissors tool on an anchor. Anchors are "stopping points" and any deletion will **never** go beyond an anchor unless the anchor is selected. (Actually, the Scissors Tool itself is rather pointless.)